# Switch to speaker when using a headphone with wearing detection

Tags: bluetooth, audio, headphones

I have a headphone with wearing detection, which pauses playback when I take off the headphone. However, with it off, I am not able to hear any notifications from the phone. I know iPhone has the feature of sending audio to the speaker when one takes off airpods. Do we have this feature in Android? Is it a problem of the phone or the headphone? In case it matters, I am using a SonyWH-1000XM4.

Comment: It depends on how the notifications are handled.. For system notifications - Android 11 and recent versions handle notifications separately from media, so you should be able to hear notifications. I can hear them using Jabra 65T Elite Bluetooth buds 2. If you are talking of app notifications, it depends on how the app is designed to handle // Assuming you are referring to first case of system notifications (please [edit] your question to make it clear) it is an issue with your headset. If it's case 2,contact the developer

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to redirect all audio back to speaker, including notifications and media sounds.

Comment: Not possible AFAIK